# PHP If statement for file_exists for image or video content from database to avoid blank space on website when no data is present

Tags: php, html, image, iframe, if-statement

Having an issue with a blog webpage I’m trying to create which includes a database. The database contains 3 columns: 'title' 'content' which are both text and 'media' which is a mediumblob for images.

```
<?php echo "img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($row['media'])."'>"; ?>
```

Everything works fine except when I don't include an image (in the data row) and just include a 'title' & 'content' it leaves a blank square on the page where an image should of been.

So firstly any advice towards an if statement (or something like that) that would check if `file_exists` (for specifically images) and display it, else exclude `<img>` (to avoid the blank square).

Something like this (which I know is totally wrong, sorry):

```
<?php

if (file_exists($row['media'])) { echo

"?php echo "img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($row['media'])."'>"; ?>" 

;} 

else { echo 

    "!--?php echo "img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($row['media'])."'>"; ?>-->"
    ;}
?>
```

Ideally with this blog, every entry will contain EITHER an image OR an embedded video via iframe, which I assume is something like this:

```
<iframe src="?php echo $emeddedLink; ?>"</iframe> (Haven't tried it as yet)
```

But I don't want a blank `<iframe>` showing on the website when using an image for the blog entry and vice versa I don't want a blank `<img>` box when using an embedded video.

Please any help would be greatly appreciated and apologies in advance for what might seem like a very basic question but I’ve been searching and can't seem to find anything really to avoid the blank square when I don't include an image in a data row... Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it. So you want to add the image/video only if the `media` value is not empty?

Comment: Yes, sorry for being confusing but simply put: I only want an image to show if i've uploaded one to the data row otherwise show title & content only... Right now when I upload entries which don't include images a blank box appears because theres no image for that specific data entry.

Comment: Instead of leaving the `<` characters out, next time select your code blocks and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K. This will indent the block by four spaces, and it will get rendered correctly. Also, use backticks for inline code so things like `<img>` display.

Comment: Thanks, will use it next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you'd have an IF statement within your loop that spits out the list of content from your database. Something like this.

```
<?php
$sql = '
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            `my_table`
';
$query = mysql_query($sql) OR die(mysql_error());
print '<table>';
print '<tr><td>Title</td><td>Content</td><td>Media</td></tr>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>'. $row['title'] .'</td>';
    print '<td>'. $row['content'] .'</td>';
    print '<td>'
    if (
        $row['media'] == '' ||
        $row['media'] == null ||
        empty($row['media']) ||
        !$row['media']
    ) {
        print 'No Media Available';
    }
    else {
        print $row['media'];
    }
    print '</td>';
    print '</tr>';
}
print '</table>';
?>
```

That should get you going if I understand what you want to do. I tried to format the code to be as easy to read for a beginner as possible. The lines that would most closely pertain to your issue above are these lines here:

```
if (
    $row['media'] == '' ||
    $row['media'] == null ||
    empty($row['media']) ||
    !$row['media']
) {
    print 'No Media Available';
}
else {
    print $row['media'];
}
```

I put all the contingencies within the `if` statement because I'm not sure what you have going on in your database. The only thing I think you'll need to change, given the fact that the image is stored as a blob in your database, is instead of printing out the `$row['media']` directly, you'd have to parse it and create an image using whatever strategy you see fit for your project.

Using your code above as an example, it would look like this:

```
if (
    $row['media'] == '' ||
    $row['media'] == null ||
    empty($row['media']) ||
    !$row['media']
) {
    print 'No Media Available';
}
else {
    print '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($row['media']) .'"/>';
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add an if statement into the template to check whether the value isn't empty

```
<?php if(!empty($media)) { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $media ?>">
<?php } ?>
```